# Little problem with display data from local server in html table with php and sql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

Today I have a little problem, with basic and maybe funny thing. Today I wanted make table with data from sql server. For that I use Xampp for that and maybe is verry common choose for that. The problem is with table because i tried to display datas with my ideas and with my knowledge and results is maybe more than what i want to do, just maybe.
Below is my scripts and I would like to mention that ***I make some versions of scripts*** and here it's just one of them.

HTML + PHP Table

```
    <div class="centred-container table">
        <table class="table-results">
            <tr class="tr-table">
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Product name</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Cod PLU</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Cod Intern</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Cod EAN/Bare</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Unitate</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Pret</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Stoc</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-table">
              <?php
              
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $nameP = $row["ProductName"];
                    $PLUP = $row["ProductPLU"];
                    $ICP = $row["ProductIC"];
                    $EANP = $row["ProductEAN"];
                    $UnitP = $row["ProductUnit"];
                    $PriceP = $row["ProductPrice"];
                    $StockP = $row["ProductStock"];

                    echo"<td>".$nameP."</td>
                        <td>".$PLUP."</td>
                        <td>".$ICP."</td>
                        <td >".$EANP."</td>
                        <td >".$UnitP."</td>
                        <td >".$PriceP."</td>
                        <td >".$StockP."</td> <br>";
                }
              ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

PHP part

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    session_start();

    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

    $codePLU = $_POST["productPLU"];
    $codeEAN = $_POST["productEAN"];
    $codeIC = $_POST["productIC"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductPLU ='$codePLU' OR ProductEAN = '$codeEAN' OR ProductIC = '$codeIC';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    }

?>
```

Here I want display (SELECT) data from database and and display that in html table. The problem is  I tried and method with `<td><?php echo $variable ?></td>` where `$varable = $row["column_name"]` and in this situation all my data is just maybe first or the last or just one row where there should have been more because I Know my sql query have more results (rows) than one row I see.
With pasted scripts I have all my rows returned by sql query but all rows is on one line and I want to be all in a classic table.
I want just little help for my little problem. I Know is just basic problem in php site but i want some case from you, or results, where I want to try for make my table a classic table without errors same as my errors above.

Sorry for my Englesh.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string like `O'Neal'.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I will work on the observations made by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your HTML table. Need to open and close each row (`<tr>`)  within the while loop. code below

```
<table class="table-results">
            <tr class="tr-table">
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Product name</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Cod PLU</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Cod Intern</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Cod EAN/Bare</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Unitate</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Pret</th>
                <th class="th-table th-univ">Stoc</th>
            </tr>
              <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $nameP = $row["ProductName"];
                    $PLUP = $row["ProductPLU"];
                    $ICP = $row["ProductIC"];
                    $EANP = $row["ProductEAN"];
                    $UnitP = $row["ProductUnit"];
                    $PriceP = $row["ProductPrice"];
                    $StockP = $row["ProductStock"];

                    echo"<tr> <td>".$nameP."</td>
                        <td>".$PLUP."</td>
                        <td>".$ICP."</td>
                        <td >".$EANP."</td>
                        <td >".$UnitP."</td>
                        <td >".$PriceP."</td>
                        <td >".$StockP."</td> </tr>";
                }
              ?>
        </table>
```